# Sort a line chart by another column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to create a line chart using the following data (first few rows):

```
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Quarter/Year   | $ Amount     | Quarter | Year      | Index |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Q1 , 2015-2016 | $ 6,614,247  | Q1      | 2015-2016 | 1     |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Q2 , 2015-2016 | $ 5,987,288  | Q2      | 2015-2016 | 2     |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Q3 , 2015-2016 | $ 4,370,943  | Q3      | 2015-2016 | 3     |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Q4 , 2015-2016 | $ 4,481,914  | Q4      | 2015-2016 | 4     |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Q1 , 2016-2017 | $ 4,498,281  | Q1      | 2016-2017 | 5     |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Q2 , 2016-2017 | $ 4,203,907  | Q2      | 2016-2017 | 6     |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Q3 , 2016-2017 | $ 63,679,729 | Q3      | 2016-2017 | 7     |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Q4 , 2016-2017 | $ 4,769,029  | Q4      | 2016-2017 | 8     |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
| Q1 , 2017-2018 | $ 7,645,517  | Q1      | 2017-2018 | 9     |
+----------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+
```

The line chart needs to have Quarter/Year on the x axis and column $ Amount on the y axis. The issue is the Quarter/Year cannot be sorted chronologically (it gets sorted alphabetically instead), so I want to sort the x axis by column Index instead. Is this possible?

Comment: What really stands for "Q1 , 2015-2016"? What is the year for this Q1 here. If Q1 belong to 2015 OR 2016 (Any One), you can generate Quarter start date for each row which will provide you a Date Hierarchy in your Mode. You can then use Quarter and Year from the Hierarchy to get the appropriate order.

Comment: Thank you. I used on the x axis both quarter and year as you suggested and sorted by both of them and it worked perfectly fine.